# Spring Boot: can't load entities, services, etc. from jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-framework-beans

This issue is widely commented in Stack Overflow, but none of the solutions seems to fit my project.

I have two independant projects (`MainApplication` and `LibraryApplication`), then I want to export LibraryApplication , and import it into  main project (this is a reduced approach for keeping things simple).

I exported the library.jar to libs/ folder in the main project, then I added the compile files instruction to  build.gradle.

The jar is indeed added to the classpath, and I can see the classes from MainApplication. So I added `@ComponentScan`, `@EnableJpaRepositories`, `@EntityScan`, etc. but none of those annotations seems to work, because only MAIN_ENTITY is created when I run the `MainApplication` project.

[LibraryApplication project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk7Rb.png)

[MainApplication project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieRUu.png)

[Only MAIN_ENTITY is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjwWj.png)

I tried many of the solutions commented in other related  questions, but none works for me:

- I moved `MainApplication.java` to an upper package level without results.
- I created an `AppConfig.java` in `LibraryApplication` project, and configured `@ComponentScan("com.app")`,`@EntityScan("com.app")`, `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.app")` and injected the class in the `MainApplication` without results.
- I removed the `.*` from my annotations, so instead of `@ComponentScan("com.app.*")` I have `@ComponentScan("com.app")` without results.

How can I achieve the expected results?

I created two github repos so you can check/download the code.

- https://github.com/ferdonof/main.git
- https://github.com/ferdonof/library.git

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Sharing the build.gradle config of each project:

***For library***

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.app'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

bootRepackage  {
    classifier = 'exec'
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

***For main***

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.app'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile files('libs/library.jar')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: What happens if, in Main you reference a class from Library? e.g. `LibraryEntity le = new LibraryEntity();` does this compile for you? I'm curious if you're getting the gradle configuration you expect.

Comment: Hi Ben! Yes, I have no compilation or runtime issues referencing classes from the library.

Comment: In main/MainApplication use `@SpringBootApplication` instead of `@SpringBootConfiguration` & `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

Instead of using *, specify the package name. So in main/MainApplication:
`@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.app.library.services" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.app.main.repositories", "com.app.library.repositories" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.app.main.domain", "com.app.library.domain" })`

Comment: Hi Luay! This didn't work for me. I have the same result: only MAIN_ENTITY is created. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot simply include one spring boot application in another. You would need the unprocessed jar to ave it included (or not make it a Spring Boot application all together).

Comment: Hi! I deleted LibraryApplication from library.jar. In fact, I don't use the main class (LibraryApplication) from MainApplication. Nothing happens, only MAIN_ENTITY is created. Could you suggest another thing? How can I get the expected result?

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this issue?